# How Consumer andThen method works internally in java functional interfaces

Tags: java, java-8

can someone let me know how the below program works internally:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Consumer<String> c = (x) -> System.out.println(x.toLowerCase());
    c.andThen(c).andThen(c).accept("Java2s.com");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the documentation [Consumer#andThen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#andThen-java.util.function.Consumer-) says:

> Returns a composed Consumer that performs, in sequence, this operation followed by the after operation. If performing either operation throws an exception, it is relayed to the caller of the composed operation. If performing this operation throws an exception, the after operation will not be performed.

which means your consumer will be accepted 3 times, like as:

```
v--- 1. c.accept("Java2s.com");        
c.andThen(c).andThen(c).accept("Java2s.com");
          ^          ^      
          |          |           
          |  3.  c.accept("Java2s.com");               
          |
2. c.accept("Java2s.com");
```

Answer (score 18):

Did you look at the code of `andThen`?

```
default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(after);
    return (T t) -> { accept(t); after.accept(t); };
}
```

It's creating a new Consumer for each call to `andThen`, finally at the end invoking the `accept` method (which is the only abstract one).

How about a different approach:

```
    Consumer<String> first = x -> System.out.println(x.toLowerCase());
    Consumer<String> second = y -> System.out.println("aaa " + y);

    Consumer<String> result = first.andThen(second);
```

Running this code is not going to produce anything, since you have not invoked `accept` anywhere just yet.

On the other hand, you can see what happens when calling `accept` on each other:

```
 Consumer<String> result = first.andThen(second);

    first.accept("Java"); // java
    second.accept("Java"); // aaa Java
    System.out.println("---------");
    result.accept("Java"); // java, aaa Java
```

`andThen` returns a composition of this Consumer with the next one.

Comment: reading the documentation again after this snippet brings you that "I see..." moment =)

Comment: `result.accept("Java");` actually produces `java\naaa Java` ;-)